# date.timezone smfony2 & php.ini

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a distant debian and configured both of my php.ini, in /etc/php/apache2/ and /etc/php/cli/ this way: `date.timezone= 'Europe/London'` (line is not commented).

So if I get on /config.php symfony tells 
me `Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris)."`

But if I run the command "php app/check.php "
`[OK]
 Your system is ready to run Symfony2 projects`

I restarted Apache after my changes, cleared symfony cache then deleted. nothing changed.

Comment: you need to check wich php.ini file you are working with, in command line you can check by typing 'php --ini', the list of the loaded files will be shown, then you could edit the right php.ini file generaly located in /etc/php.ini

Comment: Please also note that often PHP executed on the command line uses another configuration file than when executed through the web server. For the latter case, you can use, for example, `phpinfo()` to detect the location of the configuration file that is loaded.

Comment: @SylvainMARTIN @xabbuh The used one is /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and its  configured this way : `date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"`.

Comment: Run the phpinfo() from a web url as well. Perhaps you are using fpm, for which the the ini file is (probably) /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Comment: Result is /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: Did you modify that file too?

Comment: yes both are edited as post says

Comment: And did you restart apache after your latest edit?  In any event, an easy work around is to just add date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris'); to your app.php file.